# How to see only running apps in terminal and not all processes?

Tags: mac

I want to see how only the running apps and *not* a list of all processes. I want to see the same apps I see with the Force Quit Applications(Mac), but I want the list of the apps in the terminal via a command.

Can I use `top -o mem` or `ps aux` with some regex, or is there a better way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In **Terminal**:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to return name of processes whose background only is false'
```

Returns the same *applications* in **Force Quit Applications** as an unsorted *comma separated list*.

PS: To get the PIDs replace `name` with `unix id`. And to have `ps` display only applications use

```
ps ux -p $(osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to return unix id of processes whose background only is false')
```

Comment: Just make sure that Terminal, or whatever app you are using, is authorized to send Apple Events to System Events.

Comment: Do you know if there's any documentation that shows the correlation between the **states** available from `ps`, and process properties available from `System Events`?